# How to put FastLineSeries LineMode=Stairs programmatically?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, teechart

You can do it on the editor but how to code it? There is no

```
Chart1.Series[i].LineMode
```

or

```
Chart1.Series[i].Stairs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should type cast series to TFastLineSeries:

```
  (Chart1.Series[i] as TFastLineSeries).Stairs:=True;
```